# How to implement an image scrolling mechanism that has magnification and transparency effects?

Tags: ios, image, scroll, transparency, magnification

I want to implement a component like the one in the images below and I want to learn how it's done, but I couldn't search google to find a similar implementation because I couldn't know how to describe this (maybe because English is not my mother tongue).

Can you guys guide me into finding a similar implementation? I already found some coverflow libraries, but this isn't exactly a coverflow implementation. This one magnifies and changes the transparency of the images as the user scrolls.

Thx in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if i came to do this i will do like this

1. add each image to each UIImageView

   2.

   [imageView1 setAlpha:0.3];

   [imageView1 setOpaque:NO];

   [imageView2 setAlpha:0.3];

   [imageView2 setOpaque:NO];

.........like this do for all of them

or simply put this code in function and pass uiimageview

3.then add all UIImageView objects to view from back.

Comment: but the interesting part is the one after these steps